# Validating User Supplied Lucene Query In Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lucene, search-engine

I know of libraries like pylucene that give a lot of methods and classes to use lucene type search queries in your project, but I need a standalone solution to just validate that the query follows valid syntax.
i.e.

```
    naem:bob 
    ?bob
```

should raise an error, but things like

```
    \?bob 
    naem\:bob
```

should not as they are being escaped from any special meaning.
Is there any standalone way of doing this in python 2.7 that doesn't require mass use of regex?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Couldn't you just attempt to parse it and handle the `ParseException`?

Comment: @femtoRgon Normally yes, but this system I am making does not actually parse it in python. The backend handles all of that in C#. Python is our frontend (using Flask) and we want to be able to find these errors before it goes to our backend so that we can quickly tell the user there is a problem and make the app more user friendly. What we are doing in the backend takes quite a bit of time so the parse exception could happen literally 10 minutes later after the user has left.